# How to restrict an any type inside a choice group in XML schema?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, restriction, redefine

I want to redefine/restrict a complex type from the Oasis XML DSig schema.

**xmldsig-core-schema.xsd**

```xml
<complexType name="TransformType" mixed="true">
   <choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <any namespace="##other" processContents="lax"/>
      <!-- (1,1) elements from (0,unbounded) namespaces -->
      <element name="XPath" type="string"/>
   </choice>
   <attribute name="Algorithm" type="anyURI" use="required"/>
</complexType>
```

I only want to allow one explicit element type from an `##other` namespace.

**xmldsig-restricted.xsd**

**(1)** This does work:

```xml
<xs:redefine schemaLocation="xmldsig-core-schema.xsd">
   <xs:complexType name="TransformType">
      <xs:complexContent>
         <xs:restriction base="ds:TransformType">
            <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"> <!--diff-->
               <xs:element name="XPath" type="xs:string"/>
           <!--<xs:any namespace="##other" processContents="lax"/>-->
            </xs:choice>
            <xs:attribute name="Algorithm" type="xs:anyURI" use="required"/>
         </xs:restriction>
      </xs:complexContent>
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:redefine>
```

**(2)** This does also work:

```xml
<xs:redefine schemaLocation="xmldsig-core-schema.xsd">
   <xs:complexType name="TransformType">
      <xs:complexContent>
         <xs:restriction base="ds:TransformType">
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
           <!--<xs:element name="XPath" type="xs:string"/>-->
               <xs:any namespace="##other" processContents="lax"/>
            </xs:choice>
            <xs:attribute name="Algorithm" type="xs:anyURI" use="required"/>
         </xs:restriction>
      </xs:complexContent>
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:redefine>
```

**(3)** This does NOT work:

```xml
<xs:redefine schemaLocation="xmldsig-core-schema.xsd">
   <xs:complexType name="TransformType">
      <xs:complexContent>
         <xs:restriction base="ds:TransformType">
            <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"> <!--diff-->
           <!--<xs:element name="XPath" type="xs:string"/>-->
               <xs:any namespace="##other" processContents="lax"/>
            </xs:choice>
            <xs:attribute name="Algorithm" type="xs:anyURI" use="required"/>
         </xs:restriction>
      </xs:complexContent>
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:redefine>
```

Error:

```
cos-particle-restrict.2: Forbidden particle restriction: 'choice:all,sequence,elt'.
```

**(4)** This (the desired definition) does also NOT work:

```xml
<xs:redefine schemaLocation="xmldsig-core-schema.xsd">
   <xs:complexType name="TransformType">
      <xs:complexContent>
         <xs:restriction base="ds:TransformType">
            <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"> <!--diff-->
           <!--<xs:element name="XPath" type="xs:string"/>-->
           <!--<xs:any namespace="##other" processContents="lax"/>-->
               <xs:element name="InclusiveNamespaces" type="ec:InclusiveNamespaces"/> <!--diff-->
            </xs:choice>
            <xs:attribute name="Algorithm" type="xs:anyURI" use="required"/>
         </xs:restriction>
      </xs:complexContent>
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:redefine>
```

Error:

```
rcase-RecurseLax.2: There is not a complete functional mapping between the particles.
```

**(1)** shows that the restriction of `choice` is OK

**(2)** shows that the usage of only the `any` type is OK

**(3)** shows that there must be a special behavior when `any` and `choice` are combined, maybe regarding the namespaces?

**(4)** looks like the given element is not a subset of the `any` type (which is not true)

The behavior of **(3)** is also implied by the original schema which has these comments for `choice` and `sequence`:

```xml
<choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
   <any namespace="##other" processContents="lax"/>
   <!-- (1,1) elements from (0,unbounded) namespaces -->
</choice>

<sequence>
   <any namespace="##other" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
   <!-- (0,unbounded) elements from (1,1) external namespace -->
</sequence>
```

So what does this mean and how has the restriction to be defined?

**EDIT**

**(2)/(3)** The restriction is also OK, when setting `choice` to either `minOccurs=0 maxOccurs=1` or `minOccurs=1 maxOccurs=unbounded`. But why is "exactly one" not a valid restriction of "any number"? Still, when not using an `any` type, we have **(1)**.

Comment: I have upvoted your question because you have explained a complex issue very clearly. However, I am not qualified to answer it - that will probably require somebody who is associated with the W3C XML Schema working group.

Answer (score 0):

Found a partial answer...

**(4)** was resolved by removing an `import` of another schema document I wrote. I wanted to make restricting redefinitions of several targetNamespaces in multiple files and chain them together. I assume that how I did it was not a legal composition of schema documents and it resulted in some kind of circular dependency referencing(?). I re-created the document standalone and it works just the way I wrote it.

However, the main question shown in **(3)** still remains (see EDIT).